# Access rails console from AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a ROR app but it's the first time I am using AWS, usually I use heroku.

Is there any way to run the equivalent of heroku run rails c?

I want to access my rails console to update some stuff in my database.

I've checked online and tried

```
  cd /var/app current
```

It tells me that there is no such file or directory. I've also tried

```
  sudo su
  bundle exec rails c production
```

It is not loading the console but only shows me sh-3.2 at the start of the console line.

I've also tried eb ssh but it does not recognize eb.

Could someone explain to me how I can access the rails console and why I have to run the given  commands. I don't understand.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

first, you need to ssh into the EB instance. (assuming you have EB installed and ssh setup),

- eb ssh #-> this will list your EB instances
  Once in the instance, do
- cd /var/app current #-> this command will take you to the current rails source code.
- sudo su #-> switch user
- bundle exec rails c production #-> runs the rails console (like in local machine)

Comment: You generally don't need to `sudo su` and can just run `rails c`. It will automatically load the production environment.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I've  ran eb ssh and it opened, but cd/var/app current is not a directory

Answer (score 0):

That's because the path is invalid.

`cd /var/app current` -> `cd /var/app/current`

And even so, it's complicated to get environment variables and start rails console on production in elastic beanstalk.
See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms-scripts.html#custom-platforms-scripts.get-config